# Vaadin + Spring Boot + Osgi

Tags: spring-boot, osgi, vaadin, apache-karaf

Does some one already managed to setup a **Vaadin** (19 to 21) Web application using **Spring Boot** and **Osgi** (as bundle) ?

- I've managed to have a Vaadin application running under Osgi container (Karaf).
- I've managed to have a Spring Boot Application running under Osgi container (Karaf).

**But not both at the same time.**

In fact, when trying, no route are being registered and FixedVaadinServlet is never called.

Thanks for help.

Comment: OSGi with Vaadin 21 requires to use additional add-on for the OSGi support, see docs here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v21/flow/integrations/osgi/basic/#minimal-vaadin-project-for-osgi and Karaf specifics here https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/integrations/osgi/karaf Note also, the OSGi support requires Prime subscription from Vaadin https://vaadin.com/pricing

Comment: Already did it... and got prime. Problem is mixing Vaadin, Spring Boot and OSGI.

Comment: What would have been great for Vaadin, is to do something like https://github.com/mmornati/springboot-osgi-sample where you can build a Vaadin application and then integrate sub modules/views using plugins with osgi. In this project, osgi (with felix) is integrated in the application itself, and then can be packaged as a simple Spring Boot Application and deployed by it-self, without Karaf for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I don't exactly understand your question since Spring is not OSGi compatible (it just has no OSGi manifest) so I don't see how it may work at all.

Now I'm going to guess....

> I've managed to have a Vaadin application running under Osgi container (Karaf).

So your application is built as an OSGi bundle and you have deployed it to Karaf (OSGI container) and it works.

> I've managed to have a Spring Boot Application running under Osgi container (Karaf).

You have built *something* (either WAR or a Spring boot Jar) which is a Web application and you have deployed it to Karaf AS A WEB Application.
This feature provided by Karaf : it's not pure OSGi container. It allows to deploy WEB applications to it.
These Web Applications have no any relation to OSGi.

So you have no Spring application which works in OSGi: if you use another OSGi container (which doesn't support extra features like Web app deployment) then you won't be able to use Spring there since as I said Spring is not OSGi compatible.

So I don't see how it's possible to use Spring + OSGi at all.